# VBA, Looping through Directory Issues

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro which does a calculation through a directory to each workbook - it's giving me an error at `If wks.Name <> .Name Then` ,

any suggestions or any other code I could be using to apply code to my directory?

```
 Sub DirectoryExtractFilteredValues()

 'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and     perform a set task on them
'Loops trough all files in dir, error. Louisv4 in this.


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
 Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

  With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
     myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

  'In Case of Cancel
  NextCode:
 myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
     myExtension = "*.xls"

    'Target Path with Ending Extention
   myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

  'Loop through each Excel file in folder
   Do While myFile <> ""
'Set variable equal to opened workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=myPath & myFile)



     Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
   Dim wksSummary As Excel.Worksheet
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'edited so it shows in the 3rd column row +1.  Add the header and sheet name macro to this

On Error Resume Next
Set wksSummary = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unique data")
On Error GoTo 0

If wksSummary Is Nothing Then
    Set wksSummary = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    wksSummary.Name = "Unique data"
End If


'Iterate through all the worksheets, but skip [Summary] worksheet.
For Each wks In Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    With wksSummary

        If wks.Name <> .Name Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wks.Range("C:C")) Then
                Dim r As Range

  ' Get the first cell of our destination range...
  Set r = .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3)

 ' Perform the unique copy...
 If WorksheetFunction.CountA(wks.Range("C:C")) > 1 Then
wks.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , r, True
End If

' Remove the first cell at the destination range...
  r.Delete xlShiftUp
            End If
        End If

    End With

Next wks


'Headers
Range("A1").Value = "File Name "
Range("B1").Value = "Sheet Name "
Range("C1").Value = "Column Name"

 Dim intRow As Long: intRow = 2

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
If Sheets(i).Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
    Cells(intRow, 2) = Sheets(i).Name
    Cells(intRow, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    intRow = intRow + 1
End If
Next i


'Save and Close Workbook
  wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Get next file name
  myFile = Dir
   Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

EDIT: New code. Can anyone help with this? I tried the above directory code with this new code in the middle and tried making adjustments, cant get it to work.

```
    Sub looper()
 'a.t.v.5 + extra splitting of scen names(+,-,etc).
 'looping dir


Dim ws As Worksheet, wks As Worksheet, wksSummary As Worksheet
Dim y As Range, intRow As Long, i As Integer
Dim r As Range, lr As Long, myrg As Range
Dim boolWritten As Boolean, lngNextRow As Long
Dim intColNode As Integer, intColScenario As Integer
Dim intColNext As Integer

 ' Turn off screen updating and automatic calculation
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

 ' Create a new worksheet, if required
On Error Resume Next
Set wksSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unique data")
On Error GoTo 0
If wksSummary Is Nothing Then
    Set wksSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
    wksSummary.Name = "Unique data"
End If

 ' Set the initial output range, and assign column headers
With wksSummary
    Set y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Set r = y.Offset(0, 1)
    .Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("File Name", "Sheet Name", "Node Name", "Scenario Name")
End With

 ' Check each sheet in turn
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
         ' Only action the sheet if it's not the 'Unique data' sheet
        If .Name <> wksSummary.Name Then
            boolWritten = False

             ' Find the Scenario column
            intColScenario = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            intColScenario = WorksheetFunction.Match("scenarioName", .Rows(1), 0)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If intColScenario > 0 Then
                 ' Only action if there is data in column E
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(intColScenario)) > 1 Then
                     ' Find the next free column, in which the extract formula will be placed
                    intColNext = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

                     ' Assign formulas to the next free column to identify the scenario name to the left of the first _ character
                    .Cells(1, intColNext).Value = "Test"
                    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, intColScenario).End(xlUp).Row
                    Set myrg = .Range(.Cells(2, intColNext), .Cells(lr, intColNext))
                    With myrg
                        .ClearContents
                        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(LEFT(RC" & intColScenario & ",FIND(INDEX({""+"",""-"",""_"",""$"",""%""},1,MATCH(1,--(ISNUMBER(FIND({""+"",""-"",""_"",""$"",""%""},RC" & intColScenario & "))),0)), RC" & intColScenario & ")-1), RC" & intColScenario & ")"
                        .Value = .Value
                    End With

                     ' Copy unique values from the formula column to the 'Unique data' sheet, and write sheet & file details
                    .Range(.Cells(1, intColNext), .Cells(lr, intColNext)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , r, True
                    r.Offset(0, -3).Value = ws.Name
                    r.Offset(0, -2).Value = ws.Parent.Name

                     ' Clear the interim results
                    .Range(.Cells(1, intColNext), .Cells(lr, intColNext)).ClearContents

                     ' Delete the column header copied to the list
                    r.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    boolWritten = True
                End If
            End If

             ' Find the Node column
            intColNode = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            intColNode = WorksheetFunction.Match("node", .Rows(1), 0)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If intColNode > 0 Then
                 ' Only action if there is data in column A
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(intColNode)) > 1 Then
                    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, intColNode).End(xlUp).Row

                     ' Copy unique values from column A to the 'Unique data' sheet, and write sheet & file details (if not already written)
                    .Range(.Cells(1, intColNode), .Cells(lr, intColNode)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , y, True
                    If Not boolWritten Then
                        y.Offset(0, -2).Value = ws.Name
                        y.Offset(0, -1).Value = ws.Parent.Name
                    End If

                     ' Delete the column header copied to the list
                    y.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                End If

                 ' Identify the next row, based on the most rows used in columns C & D
                lngNextRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(wksSummary.Cells(wksSummary.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row, wksSummary.Cells(wksSummary.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row) + 1
                Set y = wksSummary.Cells(lngNextRow, 3)
                Set r = y.Offset(0, 1)
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next ws

 ' Autofit column widths of the report
wksSummary.Range("A1:D1").EntireColumn.AutoFit

 ' Reset system settings
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: What if you try it explicitly, `If wks.name <> wksSummary.name` ...what happens then?

Comment: @BruceWayne I get this stil: If wks.Name <> wksSummary.Name Then highlighted

Comment: What's the error it's showing? When it gets to that error, in the "Immediate Window" (press CTRL+G in VB Editor), and if you type `?wks.Name` hit Enter, then you'll see what that name is.  Do the same with `wks.Name`.  Is that also throwing an error?

Comment: When I type `?wks.Name`,  I get the name of my sheet 1. when I take `wks. name` I get error : Compile Error: Invalid Use of Property..  When I have one file in the directory it seems to work, when i got multiple it gets error.. And seems to get the first file in the directory working properly

Comment: Ah, sorry - I meant to say do the same with `?wks.Name` AND `?wksSummary.name`

Comment: I get a runtime error '-2147221080 (800401a8)': Automation error

Comment: Hmmm.  If you walk through your macro (use F8), *right before* you get to the `With wksSummary` line, enter `wksSummary.Name` into the Immediate Window.  I'm thinking that `wksSummary` isn't being set as a sheet, but something else (perhaps the sheet name itself).  Also, try `With Sheets(wksSummary)` and see if that does anything?

Comment: Also try TypeName(wksSummary)

Comment: @DonJewett , Hi Don, I get run-time 424 object required

Comment: @BruceWayne I get Compile Error, Invalid use of property.for both of your suggested commands, I did this right before while the `For Each wks In Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` was highlighted . Is there any other ways I can get the code to go through my directory?

Comment: Anyone got any ideas for my Edited post?